# Android: How to achieve ARCore and Video call simultanously using same camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming, webrtc, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm developing an Android app where the user is in an ARCore Session and at the same time should be able to share the (raw, not augmented) camera video stream in a video call.
The used technologies are:

- Unity 2018.1.6
- Google ARCore Unity SDK package
- [WebRTC Video Chat Unity package](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/webrtc-video-chat-68030) 

  The required ARCore functionality and the WebRTC Video chat work great - but only individually. Regarding having both simultaneously I'm aware it cannot work immediately; in fact having built a test app I saw that starting the video call would stop ARCore preview and reverse, dependent on what is started later. 
  So my questions are:
- Is there a way to extract the video stream from ARCore?
- How do I use this video stream as input for the WebRTC video call?

Comment: WebRTC has a feature that permits you to share an arbitrary (Unity-) camera. With this I was able to transmit the augmented video stream. Besides that, this results in a higher latency, too. Thus it does not satisfy my needs.

Comment: Found a solution yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: I succeeded in doing this. I wrote a custom Video capturer that takes frames from AR Core session and streams it via webrtc.